# Why can't I register my phone in GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on push notification using GCM for my app. As I test it on my device (Nexus 4 with CM11), I always get this error: `PHONE_REGISTERATION_ERROR`. I also checked the GCM demo from other sources and it gives the same error. The same codes work perfectly on my colleague's Huawei P6 with the same Android version as mine (4.4.4, official, not CM).

Even apps like Text+ that try to use GCM fail and give error on my device.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is here? Does it have to do anything with CM?

Comment: Check if this helps: [GCM PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cerberus-support-forum/eJxOsYqkTxo/mXwrRlq7DSEJ)

Comment: Check if you are using updated library for GCM or not. And google play services is updated or not.

Comment: @PankajKumar, I'm deliberately using the gcm.jar approach instead of newer google play services since we support SDK 10+ and many phones with android 2.3 (in Iran) doesn't come with google play store/service installed. But as the demo and the app work on other devices, I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri, I did as mentioned in the link and the strange thing is that I get no error but I don't get registration ID either! It seems like a bug with google account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I deleted my google account and add it back and the problem was solved! This link was of help (based on Shobhit Puri's comment):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cerberus-support-forum/eJxOsYqkTxo/mXwrRlq7DSEJ

I don't know what the problem was with my account but that's what solved it for me. Maybe it would help others as well.